# Can't send traffic both ways through Azure VPN Gateway?

Tags: vpn, azure, windows-server-2016

Probably a really rookie mistake, but here goes. I have a Juniper SRX and an Azure VPN Gateway, and they are connected. My on-prem VMs can connect to the Azure VMs via Vnet IP, but the reverse is not working. Neither ping nor TCP connections seem to be working. I've created a route in Windows on-prem to go to the subnet in Azure, but I can't find the VPN Gateway IP in this Vnet at all. The Gateway Subnet just shows the route as associated device, but no IP. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure a Local network gateway to communicate back to on prem?

Scroll to about halfway down this step-by-step to see how to configure your local network gateway.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2017/06/28/step-by-step-configuring-a-site-to-site-vpn-gateway-between-azure-and-on-premise/

PowerShell Steps (if needed):
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-create-site-to-site-rm-powershell#2-create-the-local-network-gateway

Comment: I did. I created a local gateway with the public IP of my on-prem Juniper SRX and specified the internal range behind in (10.x.x.x/24). Redacting the IPs for obvious reasons:

IP address
87.x.x.x
Address space
10.x.x.x/24 (all my on-prem VMs are in this range)

How do the Azure VMs even "know" about this range? Is it magically added to their gateway? I also see no taken IPs in the Gateway Subnet.